# Context Menus in Nautilus (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: nautilus

I have a horrible feeling that I am missing something very obvious, but here goes!

Nautilus has a handy context menu containing useful options like "Open in Terminal". Just right-click in an unused area of the window and select the option. My issue is what does one do if the window is full of files, as is often the case? In this case, the right-click menu I want is replaced with file options, and "Open in Terminal" is not available.

Comment: Aha, this works in the icons view. Unfortunately it doesn't in list view, which is the one I normally use.

Comment: Okay, I've edited my answer with a suggestion for list view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirmed, clicking between the files should work in 18.04.  Just make sure you right-click between the icons, not on the text below the icons.  I'll try to get a screenshot.

[image: Right click right here]

Unfortunately, the screenshot seems to miss the context menu for some reason: perhaps because I was just capturing the current window.  But where you see the pointer is where you need to right click to get the context menu.

#### Edit:

Alternatively, if you are in the list view and you have a right click key on your keyboard, you can simply hit that key on your keyboard directly after first opening the folder (no files yet selected).  If there is a file selected, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> will unselect it.

Comment: Ctrl+Space followed by shift F10 does indeed work. Thanks! It's a bit inelegant, though.

Comment: Sorry, it's the best I could think of... :)  If it answers the question, feel free to click the green accept mark to show future readers.

Comment: Remains that it is impossible with the mouse. Yet a better approach with the keyboard is to use the shortcutkey Ctrl+F10

Answer (score 0):

In *list-view*, before selecting any folder or file, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Right-Click</kbd> and context-menu will be related to the parent folder.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. However, for me <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Right-Click</kbd> seems identical to <kbd>Right-Click</kbd> when no files are selected.

Comment: Also for me, this does not work